# sharing angular project on web

Tags: angular, web

when I make a project with angular this project take place at my disk more than 160 mb so if I share the project like this it'll be problem because every use will download 160 mb data for a page so what I have to do

Comment: Not enough information here. Also - not all generated files are necessarily downloaded by the browser.

Comment: Were you wanting to share the actual project code with anyone? Or publish the actual project onto the web? Question is not clear. If the former, you could publish to GitHub or some such.

Answer (score 1):

The size on your disk does not represent the same size on the web. Whenever you build your project there is an option to build as production, the folder dist will be way less data that's what's sent to the browsers.
https://www.dottedsquirrel.com/angular-production-ready/
this articles talk about how big is the final size for the broswer in this example it was 3.9MB

Here you can learn a bit more about the build process
https://angular.io/guide/build
also there's a section in angular where you can set a budget limiting the app size.